# Direct link or html code to get facebook likes by cliking in a picture

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-like

I need a method to get likes for my facebook page directly by cliking on a picture
I mean when a visitor of my website click in a specific picture he automaticaly likes my page
with facebook social plugin I got this [link](http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http://facebook.com/gunybags&width=450&height=80&colorscheme=light&layout=standard&action=like&show_faces=true&send=true) but it doesn't make you liking the page automaticaly you need to click the like button and confirm

I don't know how to get that link or html code , "I visited a website uses this method"

I hope you can help me

Answer (score 1):

I researched this as well but I can confirm you that, since this could be easily abused to mislead the client and obtain a load of likes, **it is not possible** in an official, Facebook-approved way.